# build bootstrap twitter grid container full width (full screen) without fluid

Tags: grid, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, css-position

I want build a web application in full screen with twitter bootstrap framework. I'm testing bootstrap responsive css, but I don't like that when window browser resize, page content change position.
So I want a full bar on top, a left bar, a center content, and a right bar, and finaly a footer, and when browser resize I don't want that element change position (not fluid). I want also use a grid (span5,offset4 etc) in full screen mode. Practically a grid of columns large 50px that occupy all screen size. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer everything but a good starting point would be to comment out the conditional CSS in the bootstrap CSS.

If you go to the `bootstrap-2.1.1.min.css`
The very last line that starts with `@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:979px){`
Comment that and the rest of the page out.

This will stop elements from changing position on resize. Then you can do your own code to position what you need.

Hope this helps.